# Hows the syntax to getProperty dynamically?

Tags: groovy, dynamic, getproperty

Is this possible and if, how?

```
item.foo = "moo"

def x = "foo"
item.[x] = "moo"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure I get your question, but...

```
def item = {
    def foo
}
def x = "foo"
item[x] = "moo"

assert item[x] == "moo"
assert item.foo == "moo"
```